# Magento 2 create multi db table in module

Tags: mysql, database, magento2

I have create a module with name `MyCompany\MyModule`. And in this module, I want to create about 3 or 4 db table such as: greeting_message, greeting_post, greeting_comment. Then, I created `Setup` folder under `MyCompany\MyModule` and adding a file `InstallSchema.php`
Here is the code:

```
<?php

/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace MyCompany\MyModle\Setup;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;

/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        /**
         * Create table 'greeting_message'
         */
        $table = $setup->getConnection()
            ->newTable($setup->getTable('greeting_message'))
            ->addColumn(
                'greeting_id',
                \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                null,
                ['identity' => true, 'unsigned' => true, 'nullable' => false, 'primary' => true],
                'Greeting ID'
            )
            ->addColumn(
                'message',
                \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                255,
                ['nullable' => false, 'default' => ''],
                'Message'
            )->setComment("Greeting Message table");
        $setup->getConnection()->createTable($table);
    }
}
```

It's seem that we only create 1 table in the file. So, are there some ways to create multi db table in one module?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use copy-paste your code for one table and do the same with the other. Here are for all the tables, change the columns to your requirements.

```php
<?php

/**
* Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
* See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/

namespace MyCompany\MyModle\Setup;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;

/**
* @codeCoverageIgnore
*/
class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{
    /**
    * {@inheritdoc}
    * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
    */
    public function install(
        SchemaSetupInterface $setup,
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    )
    {
        /**
         * Create table 'greeting_message'
         */
        $table = $setup->getConnection()
            ->newTable($setup->getTable('greeting_message'))
            ->addColumn(
                'greeting_id',
                \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                null,
                [
                    'identity' => true,
                    'unsigned' => true,
                    'nullable' => false,
                    'primary' => true
                ],
                'Greeting ID'
            )
            ->addColumn(
                'message',
                \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                255,
                [
                    'nullable' => false,
                    'default' => ''
                ],
                'Message'
            )
            ->setComment("Greeting Message table");

        $setup->getConnection()->createTable($table);

        /**
         * Create table 'greeting_post'
         */
        $table = $setup->getConnection()
            ->newTable($setup->getTable('greeting_post'))
            ->addColumn(
                'greeting_id',
                \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                null,
                [
                    'identity' => true,
                    'unsigned' => true,
                    'nullable' => false,
                    'primary' => true
                ],
                'Greeting ID'
            )
            ->addColumn(
                'message',
                \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                255,
                [
                    'nullable' => false,
                    'default' => ''
                ],
                'Message'
            )->setComment("Greeting Message table");

        $setup->getConnection()->createTable($table);

        /**
         * Create table 'greeting_comment'
         */
        $table = $setup->getConnection()
            ->newTable($setup->getTable('greeting_comment'))
            ->addColumn(
                'greeting_id',
                \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                null,
                [
                    'identity' => true,
                    'unsigned' => true,
                    'nullable' => false,
                    'primary' => true
                ],
                'Greeting ID'
            )
            ->addColumn(
                'message',
                \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                255,
                [
                    'nullable' => false,
                    'default' => ''
                ],
                'Message'
            )->setComment("Greeting Message table");

        $setup->getConnection()->createTable($table);
    }
}
```